# ajax form for load a specific div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am trying just load in my form the error message, but right now its load my form page 4 times, someone know what I did wrong? I just want load that span:

`<span class="text-danger">`

controllers:

```
  <?php
/* 
 * File Name: user.php
 */


if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //load the user model
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    //index function
    function index()
    {

        //fetch data from country table
      $data['country'] = $this->User_model->get_country();


        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules  ('passconf', 'Password Confirmation', 'trim|required');




        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            //fail validation
            $this->load->view('user_view2', $data);
        }
        else
        {    
            //pass validation
            $data = array(
                'user_email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'Password' => $this->input->post('passconf'),
                //encrypting pass on database.
                'Password' => password_hash('passconf', PASSWORD_BCRYPT),

            );

            //insert the form data into database
            $this->db->insert('test', $data);

            //display success message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You Are Now Registered</div>');
            redirect('user/index');
        }

    }

    //custom validation function for dropdown input
    function combo_check($str)
    {
        if ($str == '-SELECT-')
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('combo_check', 'Invalid %s you need pick one');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    //custom validation function to accept only alpha and space input
    function alpha_only_space($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^([-a-z ])+$/i", $str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_only_space', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets or spaces');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

user_view.php

```
<?php 
        $attributes = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "id" => "userform", "name" => "userform");
        echo form_open("user/index", $attributes);?>

      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row colbox">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
            <label for="email" class="control-label">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
            <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="type your email here" type="text" class="form-control"  value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>

  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row colbox">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4">
                    <label for="passconf" class="control-label">Password</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8">
                    <input id="passconf" name="passconf" placeholder="your password" type="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('passconf'); ?>" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('passconf'); ?></span>
                </div>
                </div>

</div>
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-lg-8 col-sm-8 text-left">
            <input id="btn_add" name="btn_add" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert" />
            <input id="btn_cancel" name="btn_cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" value="Cancel" />
        </div>
        </div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
```

jquery code

```
 var frm = $('#userform');
    frm.submit(function (ev) {
        $.ajax({
            type: frm.attr('method'),
            url: frm.attr('action'),
            //data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                $(".text-danger").html(data);
            }
        });

        ev.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Please paste your full code, including the script where your form goes and the full form.

Answer (score -1):

`frm.submit` will post the form back to the server in addition to your ajax call, you need to add `return false;` after the `ev.preventDefault();` if you dont want to post the form back to the server.

Comment: I guess it would be good to have an explanation of why this was down voted otherwise one cannot learn